# Get system directory path

Tags: autoit

I want to upload an image file using an AutoIt script:

```
WinWaitActive("Open")
Send("D:\sprint8execution\gGastro-mvn\tmp.png")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

How to give the system-defined path in the script so that if the script runs on any other machine it goes to applicable directory and fetches the image from there?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [the AutoIt macros](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm). `@ScriptDir` is the directory that includes the current running script.